# Sudoku Grid in Unity 5

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity.

I am converting my Sudoku game written in WPF to Unity2D. I converted everything. However I cant achieve 9*9 grid with Buttons as I did in WPF.

In WPF I created 81 buttons with same event. So when it is called I jsut got their position displayed keyboard with only numbers that cell allowed.

Here is what I needed

[image]
Here is what I did.

1: I inserted canvas then tried vertical layout(for adding 3 rows) without success

2: Then I tried grid layout with canvas with fixable count column no success

3: grid layout with flexible option still no result.

I also tried via coding using GUI.BOX, and all still the result is not good.

How can I do it?

Comment: Unity beginner tutorials https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `GridLayout`, it is only for fixed size "icons" - irrelevant here, do not use.

First use `VerticalLayoutGroup`

include ..

[image]

Don't forget you must put a `LayoutElement` **on each of your three items**.

Get that working first.

Then, for your MIDDLE item, add a horizontal group and make that work.

Comment: I did as you said.   First added vertical layout with layout element flexible width hight checked. Then added 3 canvas to the main canvas. Then repeated 1st step. For middle canvas added horizontal layout. However I am unable to re-size canvas and buttons as I needed. How do I do that?Do I need to add content size filter?

Comment: I already did with flexible width hight checked. Still unable to resize

Comment: Actually you want only one canvas (the top level, which is added automatically when you add any other ui object). The rest should be panels e.g.

Comment: exactly, only one **canvas**, @AjitHegde

Comment: Do I have to add Content Filter for every layout or only ones

Comment: Its working with Content Filter but Now they are fitting based on content size. Its getting difficult for me from WPF autoresize to set size in everything.  Can you show me working screen shot of your only 1st panel and canvas settings?

Comment: Any good tutorial on UI design with latest API. I have books but they use old API not the new ones.